# Jumping element by element when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs with the total height of the viewport and a button for scrolling from one to another with ScrollTo jquery plugin. The problem is that I want to prevent the posibility of manual scroll.

I want that when someone scrolls with mouse down, the browser scroll automatically to the second view, and when I scroll to top gets the previous view.

I don't know if I'm explaining well, here an example: http://orangina.eu/heritage

Try to scroll in this webpage, this is what I need.

Thanks!

Comment: *"The problem is that I want to prevent the posibility of manual scroll."* **Why**? Why surprise your visitors with weird behavior when they try to do something normal? People don't *like* doing X, which always gets them Y, and getting Z instead.

Comment: In concept, its a vertical html slider. flexbox

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this technique has been used by companies like Apple, Facebook, Tumblr, Flickr, Sony... for advert sites. It seems it is not that bad from the UX point of view in some cases. There are good and bad uses of that technique, but we can not forget about the good ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all replies!

I solved my problem, instead of using standard scrolling I used the translateY css property. Setting a data-id to each page layer and doing translateY(100%, 200%, 300%...) every time I want to scroll down/up.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong but it looks to me like you're trying to disable the browsers default scrolling behaviour, attach events to scroll up and scroll down and scroll up or down to the height of the page's height.

The way I would do this is disable the browser's default scrolling behaviour with `overflow:hidden` to the body and html.

Then you can bind the jQuery "mousewheel" and "DOMMouseScroll" to the div checking for "event.originalEvent.detail > 0" or "e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0" for down scrolling or else for scrolling up.

Finally add your function call inside the if or else depending on the downscroll or upscroll.

I can write the code if you want but it might help you more if you try this yourself.

Comment: Yes! You are correct. The problem is that if I put overflow: hidden, and I try to scroll to an specific div id (currently I'm using the scrollTo jQuery plugin), the page doesn't move. If I put overflow:hidden how can I move to the div that I want?

Comment: If there is a button to be clicked to change the div then you can simply do $("....").click() to simulate the button click inside the if and else condition. Additionally, you will need to write some more code to detect the page you're on and move up and down according to the scroll - up or down.

Comment: The site won't be able to scroll if you use `overflow:hidden`. The site of your link is using `translateY` for a container, it is not using `scrollTo`. Please see my answer for a faster way to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that same effect by using [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) plugin for jQuery.

- Compatible with old browsers such as IE 8.
- Touch devices compatible
- CSS3 animations improving performance
- Lots of options, callbacks and methods.