# Scroll elements by using translateY

Tags: html, css, translate

I decided to make myself a new startpage as a way of learning flexbox and few other things. Now my problem is that I have a div which has few other divs in it which are scrollable. But I don't want to use normall scrolling, I want something that would move the whole div if I scrolled with my mouse, I came to conclusion that I will have to use translateY, but I have no idea on how to use it

Here is the (simplified) code;

```css
#container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.set {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="set">
    <a>...</a>
    <a>...</a>
  </div>
  <div class="set">
    <a>...</a>
    <a>...</a>
  </div>
  <div class="set">
    <a>...</a>
    <a>...</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for that you need to `define fix height container like height:25px;`

Comment: @BhargavChudasama I came to the translateY solution based on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27271871/jumping-element-by-element-when-scrolling the answer isn't really descriptiv on how he achived it tho. He used divs with total viewport height and then doing translateY (100%, 200%, ...) when scroling. I was hoping if somone could tell me how to achive this in bit more detail

Answer (score 0):

Check out with this CSS:

```
div.set { 
   margin:5px; 
   padding:5px; 
   width: 500px; 
   height: 110px; 
   overflow: auto; 
}
```

You need to use `overflow:auto;` or `overflow-x: auto;` property for div by triggering class name. 
Hope this helps!